# how does datepicker work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a form that requires datepicker in jquery. I am using the normal jquery-ui datepicker library.

Now the problem is it is not working and another problem is I can't show u the script as it is very complex it has various show and hides.

Now can anyone please explain to me how the datepicker works so i can solve the issue.From what i know it appends a div that has the calender and it's structure in it and a hasDatepicker class is appended to the id on which datepicker is set.

and there is one more thing i get a error when clicked on textbox,error is--

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:123**
>
> **$.extend._generateHTML jquery-ui.min.js:123**
>
> **$.extend._updateDatepicker jquery-ui.min.js:123**
>
> **$.extend._showDatepicker jquery-ui.min.js:123**
>
> **b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3**
>
> **v.handle**

Please give a simple explanation about datepiceker as i am a very new at these things.I think something is wrong while i do hideing and showing of div or in initilization.

If possible tell me a proper way to do the initilization.

Comment: try to use jquery 1.8 or below than try

Comment: this does not helps...
i know previous versions removes the error but it is still there

Comment: use jQuery UI 1.9.2 with jquery1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have a input tag as below

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

and then initialise the UI control as below

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

make sure to import jQuery framework first then jquery UI framework next.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Check out this <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/4VM2b/)**</kbd>

Make sure to read the [official documentation here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

Just include the **jQuery Migrate plugin** immediately after the script tag for jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: nope still doesnt help..
the div which appends at the bottom of id it is not appended in my source.i checked it in through inspect element

Comment: try adding it after the `jquery-ui.min.js` or the UI js you have, like above...